# Boto3 kinesis video stream: Error when calling the GetMedia operation

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kinesis

Under the boto3 docs: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/kinesis-video-media.html#KinesisVideoMedia.Client.get_media

it says that I need to run the `GetDataEndpoint` API first to get an endpoint before I run `GetMedia` but it doesn't say how to feed that endpoint in?

So I have tried to run:

```
import boto3

kinesis_media = boto3.client('kinesis-video-media' region_name='region')

stream = kinesis_media.get_media(StreamARN='my-arn',
         StartSelector={'StartSelectorType': 'EARLIEST'}) # this is not the endpoint
```

and that returns:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the GetMedia operation: <AccessDeniedException>
  <Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>
```

I am guessing cause endpoint wasn't specified but the clients of type `kinesis-video-media` don't have the `get_data_endpoint` method which is required to get the endpoint url?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, use the `kinesisvideo` client to obtain an Endpoint:

```
import boto3

kinesis_client = boto3.client('kinesisvideo',region_name='us-west-2')

response = kinesis_client.get_data_endpoint(StreamARN='...ARN...',APIName='GET_MEDIA')
```

The `response` variable contains:

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '...', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '...', 'date': 'Tue, 10 Apr 2018 08:22:59 GMT', 'content-length': '74', 'content-type': 'application/json'}}, u'DataEndpoint': u'https://s-4010cf70.kinesisvideo.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'}
```

Then, call the `kinesis-video-media` client with the given endpoint:

```
video_client = boto3.client('kinesis-video-media',endpoint_url='https://s-4010cf70.kinesisvideo.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',region_name='us-west-2')

stream = video_client.get_media(StreamARN='arn:aws:kinesisvideo:us-west-2:...',StartSelector={'StartSelectorType': 'NOW'})
```

The `stream` variable contains:

```
{u'ContentType': 'video/webm', u'Payload': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f1fab294850>, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '...', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '...', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'content-type': 'video/webm', 'date': 'Tue, 10 Apr 2018 08:27:19 GMT'}}}
```

Comment: Hey @John Rotenstein  So I want to feed the audio stream output of the Kinesis stream to Transcribe service and get realtime audio to text conversion is it feasible ?  Am concern about which format kinesis deliver (I hope its Payload format) and will trancoder able to support it or any way I can convert to transcoder understandable format (hope it supports only 'mp3'|'mp4'|'wav'|'flac' ) ?

Comment: @sudhirtataraju Please create a new question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.

Comment: Created new question: 
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204098/how-to-feed-the-audio-stream-output-of-the-aws-kinesis-video-stream-to-aws-trans           please help