# aws cli get media command

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to use the amazon cli to get media from an active kinesis stream.

the command I am trying is:

```
 aws kinesis-video-media get-media --stream-name testStream --start-selector '{ "StartSelectorType":"NOW" }' --endpoint-url 'https://<code>.kinesisvideo.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'
```

but I get:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] 
[parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: too few arguments
```

according to the docu, `StartSelectorType` is the only flag I really need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [get-media Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kinesis-video-media/get-media.html) says that you also need to provide an `outfile`:

```
get-media
[--stream-name <value>]
[--stream-arn <value>]
--start-selector <value>
outfile <value>
```

See also: [Boto3 kinesis video stream: Error when calling the GetMedia operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748934/174777)