# How to feed the audio stream output of the AWS Kinesis video stream to AWS Transcribe service?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-kinesis, amazon-transcribe

How to feed the audio stream output of the AWS Kinesis video stream (KVS) to AWS Transcribe service and get realtime audio to text conversion? I ingested audio via amazon connect to KVS(Kinesis video stream), My concern is, which format kinesis video stream (KVS) deliver (I hope its Payload format) and will Transcribe service able to support it or any way I can convert to Transcribe service understandable.

Comment: @John Rotenstein  created a new question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746612/boto3-kinesis-video-stream-error-when-calling-the-getmedia-operation), please help me.

Comment: What makes you think that such a connection is possible? Do you have any reference material? All I could find was [aws-samples/amazon-connect-realtime-transcription: Transcribe Live Customer Audio for Amazon Connect using Amazon Kinesis Video Streams and Amazon Transcribe](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-connect-realtime-transcription), which uses AWS Lambda to trigger AWS Transcribe. What end-goal are you wanting to achieve (eg what is your input and what is your desired output)?

Comment: @John Rotenstein Yes the github link you pasted is what am trying to achieve, but in that link to achieve I should know java, I know python so I decided to go with python,awscli or boto module . my flow is aws-connect---push data to --->Kinesis -------> transcoder ----> text ------> pick required using comprehend----> insert in database.    Realtime customer call I want to transcribe, no offline idea, its a requirement to be done live so using Kinesis else would saved audio to S3 then converted using Transcoder

Answer (score 1):

For me, I tinkered with the AWS CLI, two stage process although the output from the `get-data-endpoint` is sent directly for a single command line execution:

```bash
export ARN=arn:aws:kinesisvideo:XXX
aws kinesis-video-media get-media --stream-arn ${ARN} --start-selector StartSelectorType=EARLIEST outfile --endpoint-url `aws kinesisvideo get-data-endpoint --stream-arn ${ARN} --api-name GET_MEDIA --output text`
```

that got me the file I could then deal with as I needed... obviously, all my AWS credentials and so on were configured.

HTH - Robert...

Comment: output is text ? could you able play the output as its a media ?

Comment: That `aws` command downloads to `outfile` (and worth checking what `StartSelectorType` value you are using), but you'll probably find the file isn't much use anyway, you'd want to follow the implementation from the github link @john-rotenstein provided...